# Counting differences

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on SQL Server Management Studio.

I have a table like this : there is multiple groups (D934, D987,...). Within those groups there is multiple subgroups called 'Variant' (A,B,C,...). Within those Variants there is multiple Idents. For each Ident, there is a variable number of Position (Position 10,20 and 40 for Ident 11436176, and position 10,30, 40 for Ident 11436180). For each position, there is a corresponding Value.

```
Group  |  Variant   |  Ident      |  Position  |   Value
-------+------------+-------------+------------+------------
D934   |     A      |  11436176   |   10       |   12548798
D934   |     A      |  11436176   |   20       |   89846465
D934   |     A      |  11436176   |   40       |   98764544
D934   |     A      |  11436180   |   10       |   12548798
D934   |     A      |  11436180   |   30       |   89846487
D934   |     A      |  11436180   |   40       |   98764999
D934   |     B      |  ...        |   ...      |   ...
D934   |     ...    |  ...        |   ...      |   ...
D987   |     A      |  ...        |   ...      |   ...
D987   |     B      |  ...        |   ...      |   ...
D987   |     ...    |  ...        |   ...      |   ...
...    |     ...    |  ...        |   ...      |   ...
```

My goal is to build a query to compare every ident **within the same Group and Variant**, with the creation of a new calculated column counting the differences between the Idents.

When comparing two idents, I compare every positions. If for the same position they have a different Value, that's +1 difference. If a position exists for one ident, but no for the other, that's +1 difference. Here should be the result table:

```
Group  |  Variant   |  Ident 1    |  Ident 2   | Differences
-------+------------+-------------+------------+------------
D934   |     A      |  11436176   |   11436176 |   0
D934   |     A      |  11436176   |   11436180 |   3
```

Explanation:
I am comparing Ident 11436176 and 11436180. They both have position 10, and the same value for this position. Then Ident 11436176 has position 20, but Ident 11436180 does not, so that's 1 difference. Then Ident 11436180 has position 30, but Ident 11436176 does not, so that's 1 difference. Then they have both the position 40, but different values, so that's 1 difference. The total is 3 differences.

I think a good start is to do a join on the table itself to have something like this:

```
Group  |  Variant  |  Ident 1 |  Ident 2 | Position 1 |  Position 2 | Value 1  | Value 2  | Differences  
-------+-----------+----------+----------+------------+-------------+----------+----------+------------
D934   |     A     | 11436176 | 11436176 |     10     |     10      | 12548798 | 12548798 |     0
D934   |     A     | 11436176 | 11436176 |     20     |     20      | 89846465 | 89846465 |     0
D934   |     A     | 11436176 | 11436176 |     40     |     40      | 98764544 | 98764544 |     0
D934   |     A     | 11436176 | 11436180 |     10     |     10      | 12548798 | 12548798 |     0
D934   |     A     | 11436176 | 11436180 |     20     |     NULL    | 89846465 | NULL     |     1
D934   |     A     | 11436176 | 11436180 |     NULL   |     30      | NULL     | 89846487 |     1
D934   |     A     | 11436176 | 11436180 |     40     |     40      | 98764544 | 98764999 |     1
```

Then to do a group by to sum the differences, to obtain something like this:

```
Group  |  Variant   |  Ident 1    |  Ident 2    |   Differences
-------+------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
D934   |     A      |  11436176   |   11436176  |   0
D934   |     A      |  11436176   |   11436180  |   3
```

Thank you very much, I am struggling with this issue.

Comment: More than 2 samples would be helpful. This just looks effectively like `ROW_NUMBER() -1`

Comment: Please provide insert table and create table scripts.

Comment: Your best not-working attempt is still missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have extended your sample data, because it is very easy to get incorrect query without all variations of `Group`, `Variant`, `Ident` in the sample data.

Essentially, we need a composite key that consists of `(Group, Variant, Ident)`.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(Gr varchar(50), Variant varchar(50), Ident varchar(50), Position varchar(50), Val varchar(50));
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('D934', 'A', '11436176', '10', '12548798'),
('D934', 'A', '11436176', '20', '89846465'),
('D934', 'A', '11436176', '40', '98764544'),
('D934', 'A', '11436180', '10', '12548798'),
('D934', 'A', '11436180', '30', '89846487'),
('D934', 'A', '11436180', '40', '98764999'),

('D934', 'A', '21436176', '10', '12548798'),
('D934', 'A', '21436176', '20', '89846465'),
('D934', 'A', '21436176', '40', '98764544'),
('D934', 'A', '21436180', '10', '12548798'),
('D934', 'A', '21436180', '30', '89846487'),
('D934', 'A', '21436180', '40', '98764999'),

('D934', 'B', '11436176', '10', '12548798'),
('D934', 'B', '11436176', '20', '89846465'),
('D934', 'B', '11436176', '40', '98764544'),
('D934', 'B', '11436180', '10', '12548798'),
('D934', 'B', '11436180', '30', '89846487'),
('D934', 'B', '11436180', '40', '98764999'),

('D934', 'B', '21436176', '10', '12548798'),
('D934', 'B', '21436176', '20', '89846465'),
('D934', 'B', '21436176', '40', '98764544'),
('D934', 'B', '21436180', '10', '12548798'),
('D934', 'B', '21436180', '30', '89846487'),
('D934', 'B', '21436180', '40', '98764999');
```

**Query**

This query is rather straight-forward. It is possible that there are more efficient variants.

```
WITH
CTE_Idents
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        Gr, Variant, Ident
    FROM @T
)
,CTE_Join
AS
(
    SELECT
        T1.Gr
        ,T1.Variant
        ,T1.Ident AS Ident1
        ,T2.Ident AS Ident2
    FROM
        CTE_Idents AS T1
        INNER JOIN CTE_Idents AS T2
            ON  T1.Gr = T2.Gr
            AND T1.Variant = T2.Variant
            AND T1.Ident < T2.Ident
)
,CTE_FullJoin
AS
(
SELECT
    CTE_Join.Gr
    ,CTE_Join.Variant
    ,CTE_Join.Ident1
    ,CTE_Join.Ident2
    ,Position1
    ,Position2
    ,Val1
    ,Val2
    ,Diff
FROM
    CTE_Join
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT *
            ,CASE WHEN Val1 = Val2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Diff
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    T1.Position AS Position1
                    ,T1.Val AS Val1
                FROM @T AS T1
                WHERE
                    T1.Gr = CTE_Join.Gr
                    AND T1.Variant = CTE_Join.Variant
                    AND T1.Ident = CTE_Join.Ident1
            ) AS V1
            FULL JOIN
            (
                SELECT
                    T2.Position AS Position2
                    ,T2.Val AS Val2
                FROM @T AS T2
                WHERE
                    T2.Gr = CTE_Join.Gr
                    AND T2.Variant = CTE_Join.Variant
                    AND T2.Ident = CTE_Join.Ident2
            ) AS V2
            ON V1.Position1 = V2.Position2
    ) AS A
)
SELECT
    Gr
    ,Variant
    ,Ident1
    ,Ident2
    ,SUM(Diff) AS TotalDiff
FROM
    CTE_FullJoin
GROUP BY
    Gr
    ,Variant
    ,Ident1
    ,Ident2
ORDER BY
    Gr
    ,Variant
    ,Ident1
    ,Ident2
;
```

**Result**

```
| Gr   | Variant | Ident1   | Ident2   | TotalDiff |
|------|---------|----------|----------|-----------|
| D934 | A       | 11436176 | 11436180 | 3         |
| D934 | A       | 11436176 | 21436176 | 0         |
| D934 | A       | 11436176 | 21436180 | 3         |
| D934 | A       | 11436180 | 21436176 | 3         |
| D934 | A       | 11436180 | 21436180 | 0         |
| D934 | A       | 21436176 | 21436180 | 3         |
| D934 | B       | 11436176 | 11436180 | 3         |
| D934 | B       | 11436176 | 21436176 | 0         |
| D934 | B       | 11436176 | 21436180 | 3         |
| D934 | B       | 11436180 | 21436176 | 3         |
| D934 | B       | 11436180 | 21436180 | 0         |
| D934 | B       | 21436176 | 21436180 | 3         |
```

With the sample data that you provided

```
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('D934', 'A', '11436176', '10', '12548798'),
('D934', 'A', '11436176', '20', '89846465'),
('D934', 'A', '11436176', '40', '98764544'),
('D934', 'A', '11436180', '10', '12548798'),
('D934', 'A', '11436180', '30', '89846487'),
('D934', 'A', '11436180', '40', '98764999');
```

Result is

```
| Gr   | Variant | Ident1   | Ident2   | TotalDiff |
|------|---------|----------|----------|-----------|
| D934 | A       | 11436176 | 11436180 | 3         |
```

### How it works

I recommend to run the query cte-by-cte and examine intermediate results to understand how it works.

I start with making a list of keys in `CTE_Idents`. A key here is a unique combination of `(Group, Variant, Ident)`

**CTE_Idents**

```
| Gr   | Variant | Ident    |
|------|---------|----------|
| D934 | A       | 11436176 |
| D934 | A       | 11436180 |
| D934 | A       | 21436176 |
| D934 | A       | 21436180 |
| D934 | B       | 11436176 |
| D934 | B       | 11436180 |
| D934 | B       | 21436176 |
| D934 | B       | 21436180 |
```

Then we need to make all possible pairs of Idents. This is done in `CTE_Join` where we join Idents with themselves. Note filter `T1.Ident < T2.Ident` - we don't need the same pair twice.

**CTE_Join**

```
| Gr   | Variant | Ident1   | Ident2   |
|------|---------|----------|----------|
| D934 | A       | 11436176 | 11436180 |
| D934 | A       | 11436176 | 21436176 |
| D934 | A       | 11436180 | 21436176 |
| D934 | A       | 11436176 | 21436180 |
| D934 | A       | 11436180 | 21436180 |
| D934 | A       | 21436176 | 21436180 |
| D934 | B       | 11436176 | 11436180 |
| D934 | B       | 11436176 | 21436176 |
| D934 | B       | 11436180 | 21436176 |
| D934 | B       | 11436176 | 21436180 |
| D934 | B       | 11436180 | 21436180 |
| D934 | B       | 21436176 | 21436180 |
```

Now for each pair of Idents with the same Group and Variant we need to look at their Positions. This is done in `CTE_FullJoin`. For each pair `Ident1` and `Ident2` we take all Positions and Values for `Ident1` in subquery `V1` and all Positions and Values for `Ident2` in subquery `V2`.

Then we use `FULL JOIN` to join `V1` and `V2` to match those Positions that are the same and also include those Positions that don't match. Then we compare values and determine if they are the same or different in the `CASE` expression.

**CTE_FullJoin**

```
| Gr   | Variant | Ident1   | Ident2   | Position1 | Position2 | Val1     | Val2     | Diff |
|------|---------|----------|----------|-----------|-----------|----------|----------|------|
| D934 | A       | 11436176 | 11436180 | 10        | 10        | 12548798 | 12548798 | 0    |
| D934 | A       | 11436176 | 11436180 | NULL      | 30        | NULL     | 89846487 | 1    |
| D934 | A       | 11436176 | 11436180 | 40        | 40        | 98764544 | 98764999 | 1    |
| D934 | A       | 11436176 | 11436180 | 20        | NULL      | 89846465 | NULL     | 1    |
| D934 | A       | 11436176 | 21436176 | 10        | 10        | 12548798 | 12548798 | 0    |
| D934 | A       | 11436176 | 21436176 | 20        | 20        | 89846465 | 89846465 | 0    |
| D934 | A       | 11436176 | 21436176 | 40        | 40        | 98764544 | 98764544 | 0    |
| D934 | A       | 11436180 | 21436176 | 10        | 10        | 12548798 | 12548798 | 0    |
| D934 | A       | 11436180 | 21436176 | NULL      | 20        | NULL     | 89846465 | 1    |
| D934 | A       | 11436180 | 21436176 | 40        | 40        | 98764999 | 98764544 | 1    |
| D934 | A       | 11436180 | 21436176 | 30        | NULL      | 89846487 | NULL     | 1    |
| D934 | A       | 11436176 | 21436180 | 10        | 10        | 12548798 | 12548798 | 0    |
| D934 | A       | 11436176 | 21436180 | NULL      | 30        | NULL     | 89846487 | 1    |
| D934 | A       | 11436176 | 21436180 | 40        | 40        | 98764544 | 98764999 | 1    |
| D934 | A       | 11436176 | 21436180 | 20        | NULL      | 89846465 | NULL     | 1    |
| D934 | A       | 11436180 | 21436180 | 10        | 10        | 12548798 | 12548798 | 0    |
| D934 | A       | 11436180 | 21436180 | 30        | 30        | 89846487 | 89846487 | 0    |
| D934 | A       | 11436180 | 21436180 | 40        | 40        | 98764999 | 98764999 | 0    |
| D934 | A       | 21436176 | 21436180 | 10        | 10        | 12548798 | 12548798 | 0    |
| D934 | A       | 21436176 | 21436180 | NULL      | 30        | NULL     | 89846487 | 1    |
| D934 | A       | 21436176 | 21436180 | 40        | 40        | 98764544 | 98764999 | 1    |
| D934 | A       | 21436176 | 21436180 | 20        | NULL      | 89846465 | NULL     | 1    |
| D934 | B       | 11436176 | 11436180 | 10        | 10        | 12548798 | 12548798 | 0    |
| D934 | B       | 11436176 | 11436180 | NULL      | 30        | NULL     | 89846487 | 1    |
| D934 | B       | 11436176 | 11436180 | 40        | 40        | 98764544 | 98764999 | 1    |
| D934 | B       | 11436176 | 11436180 | 20        | NULL      | 89846465 | NULL     | 1    |
| D934 | B       | 11436176 | 21436176 | 10        | 10        | 12548798 | 12548798 | 0    |
| D934 | B       | 11436176 | 21436176 | 20        | 20        | 89846465 | 89846465 | 0    |
| D934 | B       | 11436176 | 21436176 | 40        | 40        | 98764544 | 98764544 | 0    |
| D934 | B       | 11436180 | 21436176 | 10        | 10        | 12548798 | 12548798 | 0    |
| D934 | B       | 11436180 | 21436176 | NULL      | 20        | NULL     | 89846465 | 1    |
| D934 | B       | 11436180 | 21436176 | 40        | 40        | 98764999 | 98764544 | 1    |
| D934 | B       | 11436180 | 21436176 | 30        | NULL      | 89846487 | NULL     | 1    |
| D934 | B       | 11436176 | 21436180 | 10        | 10        | 12548798 | 12548798 | 0    |
| D934 | B       | 11436176 | 21436180 | NULL      | 30        | NULL     | 89846487 | 1    |
| D934 | B       | 11436176 | 21436180 | 40        | 40        | 98764544 | 98764999 | 1    |
| D934 | B       | 11436176 | 21436180 | 20        | NULL      | 89846465 | NULL     | 1    |
| D934 | B       | 11436180 | 21436180 | 10        | 10        | 12548798 | 12548798 | 0    |
| D934 | B       | 11436180 | 21436180 | 30        | 30        | 89846487 | 89846487 | 0    |
| D934 | B       | 11436180 | 21436180 | 40        | 40        | 98764999 | 98764999 | 0    |
| D934 | B       | 21436176 | 21436180 | 10        | 10        | 12548798 | 12548798 | 0    |
| D934 | B       | 21436176 | 21436180 | NULL      | 30        | NULL     | 89846487 | 1    |
| D934 | B       | 21436176 | 21436180 | 40        | 40        | 98764544 | 98764999 | 1    |
| D934 | B       | 21436176 | 21436180 | 20        | NULL      | 89846465 | NULL     | 1    |
```

Final `SELECT` calculates the sum of all differences for each pair of Idents.

---

I tried to `FULL JOIN` original table with itself, but I could not make it work correctly, because of the composite key and because we needed to compare subgroups of rows. That's why I explicitly created pairs of Idents and used subqueries `V1` and `V2`.

---

I strongly recommend to have the following index

```
(Gr, Variant, Ident) INCLUDE (Position, Val)
```

for this query.

Comment: Your query provides exactly what I want. On my data set I have around 1000 idents and 50000 values, the query result was returned in 1 second, without any indexes.

Comment: @JohanB, I'm glad it worked well for you. Your table is rather small  for modern hardware, so any query would work fast. If it grows to millions of rows may need to consider indexes.